# Testing CloudCode in self-hosted Parse Server

Tags: unit-testing, parse-server

I'm looking for best practices on how to setup a test environment for CloudCode in a self-hosted Parse server. I assumed that testing got easier now that we have full control over the server and the attached database; however, so far I could not find much info on that topic. So any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should test your push notification code in cloud code, and than test those functions in which you have applied master key like { useMasteKey:true }